# Google Custom Search imgSize and imgType not taken into account

Tags: json, api, search

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=XXXXX&imgType=photo&imgSize=small&q=%EF%BB%BFShrimp%2C%20Bacon.%20Avocado%20Pasta%20Salad%0D&cx=XXXXXX

When I do a custom search, it returns images and a formatted JSON as expected. The only thing that is not expected and that is not taken into account are the parameters:

imgType=photo
imgSize=small

It makes no difference for google, and I am still receiving Clipart images and very large images (in some cases larger than 2500 px).

Any ideas?

(PS: I know I could use the cse_thumbnail which are smaller, but they are way too small).

Thanks :)