# Google CustomSearch ignores imgType?

Tags: face-detection, google-search-api

It would seem that using the google CSE api always ignores my `imgType` attribute, even through their [official API test page](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list).

My request is:

```
{
    "q": "Maimi Yajima",
    "cx": "014585077406021600032:tu4nwhtmr5q",
    "searchType": "image",
    "imgType": "clipart"
}
```

But even when changing the `imgType` i'm always getting back the same results.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be a bug to me. Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167614/google-custom-search-imgsize-and-imgtype-not-taken-into-account) with no answer. Also a thread [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/5CoHO1tQl0c) about the same problem with no solution or workarounds. I couldn't find a ticket or reply from Google.

Comment: Do you have image search turned on in the CSE settings? (sanity check since no answer yet) https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630972?hl=en

Comment: @Emptyless Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not confirmed by Google, this is most possibly a bug, or Google intentionally broke the `imgType` parameter without updating their documentation.